# Ubuntu 18.04 Phpmyadmin Error After upgrading from OS 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: phpmyadmin, ubuntu-18.04

After upgrading my OS from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 I am continuously getting this error when I click in import and export menu in phpmyadmin. My full error from export menu is:

```
Warning in ./libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php#551
 count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Backtrace

./libraries/display_export.lib.php#381: PMA_pluginGetOptions(
string 'Export',
array,
)
./libraries/display_export.lib.php#883: PMA_getHtmlForExportOptionsFormat(array)
./libraries/display_export.lib.php#1099: PMA_getHtmlForExportOptions(
string 'server',
string '',
string '',
string '<div><a href="#" onclick="setSelectOptions(\'dump\', \'db_select[]\', true); return false;">Select all</a> / <a href="#" onclick="setSelectOptions(\'dump\', \'db_select[]\', false); return false;">Unselect all</a><br /><select name="db_select[]" id="db_select" size="10" multiple="multiple"> <option value="bengal_v2" selected="selected">bengal_v2</option> <option value="co_hr" selected="selected">co_hr</option> <option value="da_hr" selected="selected">da_hr</option> <option value="dart" selected="selected">dart</option> <option value="ffl_erp" selected="selected">ffl_erp</option> <option value="ffl_hr" selected="selected">ffl_hr</option> <option value="fjl_hr" selected="selected">fjl_hr</option> <option value="hrBlank" selected="selected">hrBlank</option> <option value="jcl_wash" selected="selected">jcl_wash</option> <option value="mailserver" selected="selected">mailserver</option> <option value="mm_college" selected="selected">mm_college</option> <option value="mmc" selected="selected">mmc</option> <option value="phpmyadmin" selected="selected">phpmyadmin</option> <option value="right_link" selected="selected">right_link</option> <option value="store" selected="selected">store</option> <option value="test" selected="selected">test</option> <option value="user_access" selected="selected">user_access</option> </select></div>',
integer 0,
array,
integer 0,
)
./server_export.php#47: PMA_getExportDisplay(
string 'server',
string '',
string '',
string '',
integer 0,
integer 0,
string '<div><a href="#" onclick="setSelectOptions(\'dump\', \'db_select[]\', true); return false;">Select all</a> / <a href="#" onclick="setSelectOptions(\'dump\', \'db_select[]\', false); return false;">Unselect all</a><br /><select name="db_select[]" id="db_select" size="10" multiple="multiple"> <option value="bengal_v2" selected="selected">bengal_v2</option> <option value="co_hr" selected="selected">co_hr</option> <option value="da_hr" selected="selected">da_hr</option> <option value="dart" selected="selected">dart</option> <option value="ffl_erp" selected="selected">ffl_erp</option> <option value="ffl_hr" selected="selected">ffl_hr</option> <option value="fjl_hr" selected="selected">fjl_hr</option> <option value="hrBlank" selected="selected">hrBlank</option> <option value="jcl_wash" selected="selected">jcl_wash</option> <option value="mailserver" selected="selected">mailserver</option> <option value="mm_college" selected="selected">mm_college</option> <option value="mmc" selected="selected">mmc</option> <option value="phpmyadmin" selected="selected">phpmyadmin</option> <option value="right_link" selected="selected">right_link</option> <option value="store" selected="selected">store</option> <option value="test" selected="selected">test</option> <option value="user_access" selected="selected">user_access</option> </select></div>',
)
```

I have tried replacing `count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'] == 1)` with `(count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1)` in `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php` file. but still no success.

Answer (score 1):

In line 551 `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php` 
just replace the

```
if($options != null && count($options) > 0){
```

with

```
if ($options != null && (is_array($options) || $options instanceof Countable) && count($options) > 0) {
```